# How can I concisely define multidimensional `Vec`s in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

When initializing a multidimensional `Vec` in Rust, I can use the `vec!`-macro like this:

```
vec![vec![0; 100]; 200]
```

However, this gets messy for `Vec`s of higher dimensions. Currently, I am using this:

```
vec![vec![vec![vec![vec![vec![vec![vec![0; N-1]; N-1]; N-1]; N-1]; 2]; 2]; 2]; 2]
```

This is not very concise, and also the order in which the dimensions are written is reverse to the indexing order. Is there a more concise way to do this? I am looking for something like

```
vec![0; 2, 2, 2, 2, N-1, N-1, N-1, N-1]
```

Comment: Did you try looking for a crate on crates.io that can handle multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: There is the crate `ndarray`, otherwise I believe a macro is the only way to avoid that long chain of `vec!`

Comment: I would recommend ndarray over vecs of vecs, not just for ease-of-use, but vecs use individual allocations and would result in memory fragmentation. Whereas ndarray will store all the data in a single buffer, which uses less memory and is more efficient to access.

Comment: @PeterHall @Ismail Maj @kmdreko I now tried to use the `ndarray` crate, but cannot find how to construct an 8-dimensional `Array` in the documentation. There are examples with lower dimensions (e.g. `Array::zeros((2, 2))`), but this seems to work only for up to 6 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ndarray` crate allows you to have an N-dimensional array. For anything above 6 dimensions, you can use the `ArrayD` type. You can create a dynamic dymension using `IxDyn` - [documentation with examples](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.6/ndarray/type.IxDyn.html).

Example for a 7x7x7...x7 array initialization and element access:

```rust
    let mut array_7d = ArrayD::<f64>::zeros(IxDyn(&[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]));
    let index = IxDyn(&[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    array_7d[&index] = 1.0;
```